# How do I track a mail I sent to someone that he/she forgot to reply to me in GMail?

Tags: gmail

I sometimes send request mails to my partners but as the mail is sent and in my outbox, if the person do not reply to the thread, I won't be reminded.

Is there anyway that I can build a filter or something to find out all those kind of mails? Technically I want to track all mails that sent by me but not get replied.

Thanks very much for any kind of help or discussion.

Comment: This site is not really the place for a question like this - have you tried old fashioned pen and paper?

Comment: Should go on webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Clearly not the good site for this question but still.. Try out [Boomerang Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-for-gmail/mdanidgdpmkimeiiojknlnekblgmpdll) extension.